# Why does C# not read human-like emojis?

Tags: c#, telegram, emoji

I have a telegram bot made in C# and I added a command that reads an emoji, and then sends it back. It works well with most emojis except for the human ones that can have several skin tones. However, I kept the default skin colour, but it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

EDIT: I explained wrong. You send the emoji, the program compares it with a constant with the emoji, and sends it back if it's the same. After some testing I found out the problem has to do with genders. Gender emojis do not work, as the string I compare them with doesn't seem to be correct. I tried using "emoji"+"male symbol emoji" but still doesn't work.

Comment: C# doesn't care, it's a programming language. The fault is in the implementation itself, not the language used. That said this is far to broad to answer since no details are given.

Comment: Most emojis are single Unicode code points, but skin colour is done using modifiers, which are treated as separate characters. So a human emoji with a skin tone consists of two characters, one for the emoji and then one for the skin tone modifier. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character

Comment: It sound like your encoding method is wrong.

Comment: I explained wrong. You send the emoji, the program compares it with a constant with the emoji, and sends it back if it's the same.

After some testing I found out the problem has to do with genders. Gender emojis do not work, as the string I compare them with doesn't seem to be correct. I tried using "emoji"+"male symbol emoji" but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Strings in the .NET framework are stored using UTF-16, which uses two bytes for most characters, but for for others.  In addition, some glyphs, including Emojis, are composites of multiple characters.  Unicode's rules for handling composite characters are sufficiently complex, and have changed enough over the years, that older text-handling code will often have problems handling some forms of composite characters.

The problem is that at some level, displaying a string will require breaking it down into pieces that can be rendered separately.  If a system's "display string in a single line" function understands the current rules for emojis, but an application's "display string in a word-wrapped box" function doesn't, that function may accidentally subdivide an input string between the parts of a composite character and ask the system to render each part separately; the result is a real mess.

Most likely, your issue isn't with C# per se, but with whatever is trying to display the message.  Composite character handling is so complex that very few applications will correctly handle everything required by the current standards, and none of today's applications will be likely to correctly handle everything required by the next version of the Standard.